# Knockout.js onclick button how to focus and clear the input field text

Tags: knockout.js

I have button and input field, on clicking the button i want to focus the input field also want to clear the field value. any idea ?

please note below my  html js

```
HTML:
        <div class="inputStyle03">
                        <input type="text" data-bind="value: myParentViewModel.newCustomViewSubTab, hasFocus: true" id="inputCustomViewName" placeholder="Enter a name for your customer view" />
                    </div>
      <div class="buttonStyle02 buttonStyle03Ext01 columnRight" data-bind="click: myParentViewModel.addNewCustomView">
                <a>Add New Custom View</a>
            </div>
```

JS:

```
function ParentViewModel()
{
    var that = this;
    that.myViewModelRibbon = new TabViewModel();
    that.newCustomViewSubTab = ko.observable(); //  newly adding custom view from input field

    that.addNewCustomView = function (data, event) {
        var allSubTAbs = data.myViewModelRibbon.ActiveSubTabs();
        var userDefinedCustomView = {
            "SubTabName": that.newCustomViewSubTab(), // getting the SubTabName from the input observables text box
            "IconPath": "images/icons/Document.png",
            "GroupID": "0",
            "IsMultipleActive": "0",
            "EnabledState": "enabled",
            "CallbackOnSelect": "openCommonForm"
        };
        if (!!that.newCustomViewSubTab()) {
            //if (that.newCustomViewSubTab() != null && that.newCustomViewSubTab() !== '') {
            data.myViewModelRibbon.ActiveSubTabs.push(userDefinedCustomView);

        } else {
            alert("Please enter - Define a new custom view field");
        };
    }
    return that;
}

var myParentViewModel = new ParentViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(myParentViewModel);
```

Comment: Just use two observable (one for field value, one for field focus) and set them to `''` and `true`, respectively. See http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/hasfocus-binding.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite simple to clear as observable, you just have to call it with an empty value:

```
this.myValue = ko.observable('Initial Value');

// this will clear it
this.myValue('');
```

To set the focus, you can use the `hasFocus` in conjunction with a boolean observable that hold the value.

Run the below code snippet to see it in action:

```js
var viewModel = {
   myValue: ko.observable('Initial Value'),
   cleared: ko.observable(false),
   clearValue: function() {       
       this.myValue('');   
       this.cleared(true);
    }
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<input type="text" data-bind="value: myValue, hasFocus: cleared" />
<input type="button" data-bind="click: clearValue" value="clear" />
```

Comment: Tanner: Hey in my soln the clear is working but not he focus :( Can u guess why ? HTML: <div class="inputStyle03">
                        <input type="text" data-bind="value: myParentViewModel.newCustomViewSubTab, hasFocus: cleared" id="inputCustomViewName" placeholder="Enter a name for your customer view" />
                    </div> and

Comment: JS: 
function ParentViewModel() {     that.cleared = ko.observable(false); // this will clear input field that.addNewCustomView = function (data, event) {if (!!that.newCustomViewSubTab()) {
            //if (that.newCustomViewSubTab() != null && that.newCustomViewSubTab() !== '') {
            data.myViewModelRibbon.ActiveSubTabs.push(userDefinedCustomView);
            that.newCustomViewSubTab(''); // onclicking the addnew button clearing the input field
            that.cleared(true); // onclicking the addnew button focusing the input field
        }}
    return that;
}}

Comment: Can you add the code you your question please as it's impossible to read here, and it would be useful if you could recreate the issue in a snippet or js fiddle.